# Drop-down menu goes width site

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

website http://shop.jstudio-pro.com/

Drop-down menu "Категория - 2" beyond the width of the site.

How to make a drop down menu has always been within the width of the site?

**Example of the menu structure:**

```
<ul class="mg-main-menu">
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#"></a>    
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.mg-main-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 45px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: right;
}

.mg-main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.mg-main-menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.mg-main-menu li a:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(../images-template/border-right-menu.png);
}

.mg-main-menu li:last-child a:after {
    background: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.mg-main-menu li a:hover, .active-menu {
    color: #9F84CA !important;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 180px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5 0%,#F8F8F8 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5 0%, #F8F8F8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5 0%,#F8F8F8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5 0%, #F8F8F8 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    background: #D3D3D3;
    z-index: 1;
}

.mg-main-menu li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}

.mg-main-menu li .js_test:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu.js_inline-block li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.mg-main-menu .js_arrow:after {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(../images-template/submenu-arrow.png);
}

.mg-main-menu .js_arrow:hover:after {
    display: block !important;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li a {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li a:after {
    display: none;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li.js_float {
    display: block !important;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li.js_float:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: inherit !important;
}

.mg-main-menu li .submenu li a:hover,
.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul li a:hover,
.mg-main-menu li .submenu li a.active-menu {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #9251B0),
    color-stop(1, #C963CE)
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #9251B0 0%, #C963CE 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #9251B0 0%, #C963CE 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #9251B0 0%, #C963CE 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #9251B0 0%, #C963CE 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9251B0 0%, #C963CE 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        width: (185 * Math.min($('li ul', this).length, 4)) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Since the solution is simple, I'll go ahead and mention it here. Add this to your custom CSS file to make your dropdowns open left: `ul.submenu {right: 0;}`

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem for a whole day. I know that this problem can be solved through javascript (offset), but do not know how to write code. ul.submenu {right: 0;} – does not work if the drop down menu will be in the first link. Then drop down menu will go to the left, see site now.

Comment: write html, css and javascript

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to add a class to only those menus that need shifting and apply the CSS I suggested to that class. Since your website isn't responsive, this should work just fine. It can also be done with JS, but the solution isn't trivial and would require you to learn a little yourself.

Comment: Of course I can add a class to the desired menu, but I need a universal solution that does not need to calculate the desired menu and add classes. Do you know a solution?

Comment: Hmm, there is probably a better solution, but you could do something like targeting the first or last drop down exclusively and changing the style to open right or left.

Comment: `li:first-of-type{/*code to force the drop down to open to the right of this far left dropdown*/}` then possibly another one for the last drop down and force it to open to the left.